Prove $E(X) = a$ for a pdf symmetric about $a$
Show that if $X$ is a continuous random variable with p.d.f. $f(x)$ such that $f (a + x) = f (a − x)$, then $E(X) = a.$
I did a change of variable and set $x=a+y$, but I'm having difficulty getting to the conclusion.

@SeverinSchraven why is it $−\int s f(a+s)ds$

That is for you to figure out.

@SeverinSchraven I was already able to do the first part of your hint. The part I'm having  a hard time with is showing the second part and concluding

Just use the substitution $t=-s$ and you are done...

Apparantly $X-a$ and $a-X$ have the same distribution. Then automatically they have the same expectation (provided of course that this expectation exists)

The following argument works even for distributions which are not given by a pdf such as discrete distributions.
Symmetry about $a$ means invariant under the reflection $x\mapsto 2a-x$. So
$$
   E(X)=E(2a-X)=2a-E(X)
$$
So we get $E(X)=a$.

$$\begin{align}\def\d{\,\rm d}
E(X)-a&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-a) f(x)dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty t f(a+t)dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0 t f(a+t)dt+\int_0^\infty t f(a+t)dt\\
&=-\int_0^{\infty} u f(a-u)du+\int_0^\infty t f(a+t)dt\\
&=-\int_0^{\infty} u f(a+u)du+\int_0^\infty t f(a+t)dt=0.
\end{align}$$
